# Regex for patterns like [ABC], ABC and ABCxx where xx is a number

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a text whose length can vary between 1 and 1000. I am looking to get the following sub strings extracted from the text.

1. Sub string of the form ABCxx/ABCx where ABC are always english alphabets and x/xx is a number which can vary from 0 to 99 (the numeric length is either 1 or 2). The following regex does the job for me to extract this sub string - `[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2}`
2. Sub string of the form `<space>ABC<space>`, ABC (last sub string/word in the text)and ABC (first sub string in the text). Basically here I am trying to find a 3 letter word delimited by spaces in the text.
   For getting the above matches, I have the following regex's.

```rb
[ ][a-zA-Z]{3}[ ], [ ][a-zA-Z]{3} and [a-zA-Z]{3}[ ]
```

3. Same as 2, but the three character string can also be in a box bracket like [ABC].

```rb
\[([a-zA-Z]{3})\]
```

Since the patterns are more or less similar, is there anyway to combine all 5 of them ?

Eg: `ABC catmat dogdog [rat] LAN45 eat HGF1 jkhgkj abc`

Here valid matches are `ABC`, `rat`, `LAN45`, `eat`, `HGF1`, `abc`.

Comment: can you post some sample input and desired output ?

Comment: Sorry forgot that. Just edited the question to include an example.

Comment: You can try something like [this ](https://regex101.com/r/BeEvAx/3/)

Comment: Here, "[abc]123", abc is a match as it is inside the box brackets.

Comment: If the string were "ABCD12" would "BCD12" be a match? If the string were "BCD123" would "BCD12" be a match?

Comment: No that's not a valid match (sorry for not making it obvious in the question). This regex did the trick for me (\b[a-zA-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,2})?\b)

Answer (score 2):

```
R = /
    \p{L}{3}\d{1,2}    # match 3 letters followed by 1 or 2 digits
    |                  # or
    (?<=\A|\p{Space})  # match start of string or a space in a pos lookbehind
    (?:                # begin a non-capture group
      \p{L}{3}         # match three letters
      |                # or
      \[\p{L}{3}\]     # match three letters surrounded by brackets
    )                  # end of non-capture group
    (?=\p{Space}|\z)   # match space or end of string in a pos lookahead
    /x                 # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
"ABC catmat dogdog [rat] LAN45 eat HGF1 jkhgkj abc".scan R
   #=> ["ABC", "[rat]", "LAN45", "eat", "HGF1", "abc"]
```

This regex is conventionally written (not free-spacing mode):

```
R = /\p{L}{3}\d{1,2}|(?<=\A| )(?:\p{L}{3}\[\p{L}{3}\])(?= |\z)/
```

Now consider:

```
 "ABCD123 [efg]456".scan R
   #=> ["BCD12"]
```

I believe this is consistent with the statement of the problem, but if `"BCD12"` should not be a match if it is preceded by a letter or followed by a digit (here both apply), then the regex should be modified as follows.

```
R = /
    (?<=\A|\p{Space})  # match start of string or a space in a pos lookbehind
    (?:                # begin a non-capture group
      \p{L}{3}         # match three letters
      \d{,2}           # match 0, 1 or 2 digits      
      |                # or
      \[\p{L}{3}\]     # match three letters surrounded by brackets
    )                  # end of non-capture group
    (?=\p{Space}|\z)   # match space or end of string in a pos lookahead
    /x                 # free-spacing regex definition mode

"ABC catmat dogdog [rat] XLAN45 eat HGF123 jkhgkj abc".scan R
  #=> ["ABC", "[rat]", "eat", "abc"]
```

Notice that, in both regexes, I replaced `\p{Space}` with a space character. In free-spacing mode spaces are removed before the regex is parsed, so they must be written `\p{Space}`, `[[:space:]]`, `[ ]` (a character class containing a space), `\` an escaped space character or, if appropriate, `\s` for a whitespace character (which includes spaces, newlines, tabs and a few other characters).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. This regex did the trick for me.

(\b[a-zA-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,2})?\b)

Comment: The example in your question suggest that `[rat]` should be a match, but this regex matches `rat` instead.

Comment: Edited. My mistake.